# Member.kick() does nothing (Discord bot on java)

Tags: java, permissions, discord, bots

### Main

```
    List<Member> banned=new ArrayList<>(); 
public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException { 
builder=new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT); 
String token="censored"; 
builder.setToken(token); 
builder.addEventListeners(new Main());
 List<GatewayIntent> intents=new ArrayList<>(); 
intents.add(GatewayIntent.GUILD_BANS);
 intents.add(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS); 
builder.enableIntents(intents); 
builder.build(); }
```

---

### not working part

```
if(event.getGuild().getSelfMember().hasPermission(Permission.KICK_MEMBERS))
                           say(event.getChannel(),target.getEffectiveName()+" gekickt!");
                           else
                               System.out.println("no permission");
                           if(event.getGuild().getSelfMember().hasPermission(Permission.KICK_MEMBERS))
                               System.out.println("has permission");
                           if(!banned.contains(target))
                           banned.add(target);
                           System.out.println("test3453");
    
                            event.getGuild().kick(target);
```

in the 2nd code part the bot should kick an User. In my console I see it has the permission to do so, but It doesnt kick anyone and I dont even get an error message.
Id be thankful if someone has ideas what I could have done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kick returns a `RestAction` which means you have to call `.queue()` on it. For instance: `member.kick().queue();`

See also:

- [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19%29-Troubleshooting)
- [RestAction](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/7%29-Using-RestAction)